# Concat column value and variable with specific length in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table products and another table categories.
Here is some sample data
Products

```
id    |  product_name      |  category_id
1     |  Leath Machine     |  1
2     |  Drilling Machine  |  1
3     |  Boring Machine    |  1
```

And here is category table

```
id    |   name           | symbol
1     |   SMT Equipment  | SMT
```

I want to do a select which will display me results like this

```
id    |  product_name      |  category_id  |  code
1     |  Leath Machine     |  1            |  SMT00001
2     |  Drilling Machine  |  1            |  SMT00002
3     |  Boring Machine    |  1            |  SMT00003
```

How cai do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `products`.`id`,
  `product_name`,
  `category_id`,
  CONCAT(symbol, LPAD(products.id,5,'0')) AS code
FROM products
  INNER JOIN categories
    ON products.category_id = categories.id;
```

Here is the SQLFiddle results.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3b05/5)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   select p.id,p.product_name,p.category_id,concat(symbol ,'0000',p.id) code from Products p
   inner join category c
   on p.category_id = c.id
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab2b/2)

Comment: this will not bring the desired result if there are 10 or more products. it will still fetch 0000 as string which should have been incremented.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT p.*, CONCAT(c.symbol, LPAD(p.id, 5, '0')) FROM products p 
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id=c.id;`